# Get all touches on screen

Tags: ios, ios6, c4

I'm having a small issue. I'd like to receive all touches on the screen and for each one spawn a new video. The problem is that once a video is placed then it intercepts the touch points. I tried various values to go in locationInView but without any luck so far. Am I looking in the right place?

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint pointOnScreen = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

    C4Movie *player = [C4Movie movieNamed:@"inception.mov"];
    player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    player.loops = YES;
    player.center = pointOnScreen;
    [self.canvas addMovie:player];

 }
 @end
```

Comment: I've posted the complete code at https://gist.github.com/4687770 (now with solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the userInteractionEnabled property of each video screen (assuming it is held in some sort of UIView) to NO - that way, touch events will pass through it and continue to be received by your handler.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're looking in the right place, and Chris has it right about user interaction. You should try:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint pointOnScreen = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    C4Movie *player = [C4Movie movieNamed:@"inception.mov"];
    player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    player.loops = YES;
    player.center = pointOnScreen;
    player.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self.canvas addMovie:player];
}
```

However you're going to run into an issue with adding videos. **Unfortunately, iOS / hardware only lets you have 4 video pipelines running at one time so you'll hit that pretty quickly**.

If you want to add things to the screen as you touch and drag your finger, then you could also do the above code inside of the following method:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //work your magic here
}
```

Comment: The simulator lets me add as many as I like. I'll put it on hardware and see what happens.

Beyond just tracking and killing the oldest instance, is there another way of dealing with this? I can imagine it might be possible with an OPENGL layer.

Comment: Do they all play?! If they do that would be awesome, can you post a gist with your project so I can check it out. You can have multiple opengl objects for sure, the limitation is actually with the AVFoundation pipeline. But, maybe everything's changed since I last thoroughly tested movies (in the summer!).

Comment: Yes. In the simulation they all play but I haven't tried on hardware yet. 

The link to the gist is in a comment in the original question. Is that the best place to put the link once the issue is solved or should I edit the original post?